# Swift using reduce to calculate score from an array of Boolean

Tags: ios, swift, reduce

I've the following code running good on playground to calculate score from the input array of Boolean values. I'm little confused if what I've followed is the best practice. I'm using a variable called score to get the result. Is there a better way of doing this by avoiding the extra score variable? Following is my code snippet:

```
var arr = [false, true, true, true]
var score = 0
let sum = arr.reduce(0) { (result, next) -> Int in
if next == true {
    score = score + 1
   }
return score
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try

```
let sum = arr.filter{$0}.count
```

To better understand it can be rewritten to this

```
let sum = arr.filter{ $0 == true }.count
```

but since

> ($0 == true) = $0

then it's better to have the first form

Comment: Do you mind telling me how this works as it never checks for any conditions?

Comment: the filter function will filter the array based on what inside **{}** and since the elements are bool values and that what the function expects to filter the array then it pass , have a look here  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2893557-filter

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sh_Khan. Now I understood the working and a got the precise solution.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need an extra variable - use the one that passed in (`result`, in your example). Just return `result`, or `result + 1`, depending on whether `next` is true.

```
let sum = arr.reduce(0) { (result, next) -> Int in
    if next == true {
        return result + 1
    }
    return result
}
```

That's the answer, but if you want to make your code more concise, keep reading, because we can do better.

You don't need to specify the `-> Int` part of the block. Swift knows.

```
let sum = arr.reduce(0) { result, next in
    if next == true {
        return result + 1
    }
    return result
}
```

Rather than having an `if`, you can use a ternary operator. We called this "immediate if" in the old days. Basically instead of something like this:

```
if x == 2 {
    return 3
}
else {
    return 4
}
```

You could instead write:

```
return x == 2 ? 3 : 4
```

Going back to your code, we could use a ternary operator to shorten it to:

```
let sum = arr.reduce(0) { result, next in
    return next == true ? result + 1 : result
}
```

You can actually omit the `== true` part; for testing a boolean variable, `next` is identical to `next == true`.

```
let sum = arr.reduce(0) { result, next in
    return next ? result + 1 : result
}
```

Now that our closure is down to one line, we could omit the `return`. The statement is implied as the return value.

```
let sum = arr.reduce(0) { result, next in
   next ? result + 1 : result
}
```

That's usually where I stop, but you can go one further. Parameters passed to the closure can be referenced by number: `$0` for the first, `$1` for the second, and so on. In this way, you can omit the names altogether.

```
let sum = arr.reduce(0) {
    $1 ? $0 + 1 : $0
}
```

Now it's short enough that you could put it on a single line if you wanted.

```
let sum = arr.reduce(0) { $1 ? $0 + 1 : $0 }
```